# PySpark count() can't process 684 GB .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am using PySpark to see how many times each timestamp appears in this very large data set using `count()`. My data set is from a **684 GB** .txt file. However, when I use count() it takes a very long time and eventually just stops trying to process. My work computer has 16 GB Memory and 4 CPU Cores. I am also using Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda.
Here is what I have so far:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pyspark-shellTest2').getOrCreate()
spark
```

*Output:*

```
SparkSession - in-memory

SparkContext

Spark UI

Version
v3.3.0
Master
local[*]
AppName
pyspark-shellTest2
```

Reading .txt file and selecting the columns I want to keep

```
raw_data = spark.read.options(delimiter="\t",header=True).csv("O:/Corbin/Canvas/requests_12_05_2022.txt")
Get_col = raw_data.select('timestamp_day', 'user_id', 'course_id')
Get_col.show(3)
```

*Output:*

```
+-------------+------------------+------------------+
|timestamp_day|           user_id|         course_id|
+-------------+------------------+------------------+
|   2022-09-15|425465600693903129|                \N|
|   2022-09-15|508873040735657962|193340000000014379|
|   2022-09-15|284347190388427414|193340000000014966|
+-------------+------------------+------------------+
only showing top 3 rows
```

Number of partitions (Not sure if I need to change this with `repartition()`)

```
Get_col.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

*output:*

```
5480
```

This where it should output, but it takes super long and eventually stops processing

```
Get_col.groupBy('timestamp_day').count().show()
```

[image]

Comment: On first glance it seems not much of a problem per se...  should go in O(n+k) where n is total number of entries and k is total number of unique entries. Let'say that you have 1ms per operation and 4e6 entries should be about one hour!(this numbers are just dimostrative, you should do the math by yourself),you definetively have to clean behind what you already counted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not getting any errors yet, I would not immediately assume something is wrong. You might bounce onto data skew problems for example, but it is a bit too early to conclude that.

What you can do, however, is have a look at the [Spark UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html). This is an interactive UI that runs in any browser which will give you quite detailed information about your currently running Spark application. You'll be able to see which jobs/stages/tasks are currently running and you'll be able to see whether there might be data skew issues or others.

This service runs by default on port 4040 of the machine in which your driver is running. So some examples:

- If your application is running locally, that means your driver is running locally as well. Just visit `localhost:4040` on a browser and you'll see the UI!
- If your app is running on Kubernetes, you could port-forward the driver pod's port 4040 onto your machine like so: `kubectl port-forward <driver-pod> 4040:4040`. Then you should be able to visit `localhost:4040` on your machine as well
- ...

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Once you've got the Spark UI running, you can start debugging a bit. [This](https://medium.com/swlh/troubleshooting-stragglers-in-your-spark-application-47f2568663ec) article discusses some of the things you can do.

Comment: I've used the Spark UI before. How can I know if it is a data skew issue?

Comment: I've added an extra line at the bottom of my answer, maybe that will help you! Once you find out the issue, don't hesitate coming back and telling what the problem was :)